# undefined local variable or method `discussion' for #<DiscussionsController:0x598de20>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's the error message that I'm getting

```
NameError in DiscussionsController#destroy

undefined local variable or method `discussion' for #<DiscussionsController:0x598de20>
```

I have created a DiscussionsController

```
class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @discussion = discussion.find(params[:id])

    if @discussion.present?
      @discussion.destroy
    end

    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I'm trying to allow users to delete their own discussions.
Here's the view that I'm using to allow the delete:

```
<% if current_user?(discussion.user) %>
  <%= link_to "delete", discussion, method: :delete,
                                    confirm: "You sure?",
                                    title: discussion.content %>
<% end %>
```

When I try, it goes to `http://localhost:3000/disc/7` (7 = discussion_id) and displays that error.

Part of my routes.db

```
resources :discussions, :path => "disc"
```

How can I fix this? By the way, is the DiscussionsController necessary? I only created it to def destroy.

Postcomments table for the error in the below comments

```
 create_table "postcomments", :force => true do |t|
    t.text      "content"
    t.integer   "user_id"
    t.integer   "micropost_id"
    t.timestamp "created_at",      :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.text      "comment_content"
  end
```

Postcomments model

```
class Postcomment < ActiveRecord::Base


  attr_accessible :comment_content

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :micropost

  validates :comment_content, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :micropost_id, presence: true  

  default_scope order: 'postcomments.created_at ASC'
end
```

Comment: Clearly your `postcomments` table doesn't have a `discussion_id` column. But as I said, please ask another question, because this new problem is unrelated to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discussion` should be with a capital D. Instead of:

```
@discussion = discussion.find(params[:id])
```

try:

```
@discussion = Discussion.find(params[:id])
```

It's a class you are trying to call a method on and classes always start with a capital letter in Ruby.

Comment: do you know why this error happens when I try to delete? I don't have postcomments related to discussions so I'm wondering where do I need to fix this? `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: postcomments.discussion_id: SELECT "postcomments".* FROM "postcomments"  WHERE "postcomments"."discussion_id" = 7 ORDER BY postcomments.created_at ASC`

Comment: This seems completely unrelated to your earlier question. So, no, no idea. This probably happens when you redirect to `root_path`. Please ask another question and post relevant code.